# Raspberry PI Setup commands

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I am having some trouble with this setup

[Raspberry PI Setup](https://github.com/kelly/node-i2c#raspberry-pi-setup)

I am sure it is simple, but considering that I am new to using a mac and its terminal, some things are not so linear for me.

For example, after adding the two lines:

`i2c-bcm2708`

`i2c-dev`

Do I type `:x` to save and exit to then move on to the next *sudo* command?

After typing the second *sudo* command `$ sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`
what are the correct steps to *commenting out* the blacklist?

Could someone please help me with the exact bash commands necessary to complete this setup?

Comment: `:wq` will write your file and exit vi.  (press escape first)

Comment: You can also use nano instead of vi on raspberry pi.  It might be easier!

Comment: Which line did you want to comment out?

Comment: #blacklist i2c-bcm2708  (  # is commenting out this line ) so just put # infront of the line.

Answer (score 0):

For commenting out the lines in a file, you could use `sed`,

```
sudo sed -ni '/i2c-bcm2708/s/^/#/p' /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

Example:

```
$ sed -n '/i2c-bcm2708/s/^/#/p' file
#<TH bgcolor=#7070ff>DATAbase</th> i2c-bcm2708
```

It comment out the line which contains the string `i2c-bcm2708`.

I added `sudo` because `/etc` directory would be owned by root. To edit the files owned by root, you need super user do(`sudo`) privilege.

Comment: This doesn't help me much. Thanks

Comment: @Did you face any errors while running the above `sed` command?

Comment: Yes. It returned `sed: 1: "/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-b ...": invalid command code m`

Comment: you could try `nano` for this. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf`, add comment mark on the starting of the line which contains `i2c-bcm2708`. After adding the `#` mark, press ctrl+o to save the changes made to that file.